# Write gtest to verify the class is null

Tags: c++, c++11, googletest, googlemock

I have few lines of code like below:

```
int class1::function() {
  std::unique_ptr<namespace::class2> devObjPtr(new namespace::class2);
  if (devObjPtr == nullptr) {
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

This function is present in another class in the same namespace. How can I test that piece of code using gtest or gmock?

Comment: `EXPECT_EQ(nullptr, devObjPtr);` or `EXPECT_EQ(1, function());`?

Comment: I have to simulate condition to get return value 0. How can it be simulated in gtest? Should i write the test as follows?

Comment: I have to simulate condition to get return value 0. How can it be simulated in gtest? Should i write the test as follows?
TEST_F(TestBase, Test_success)
{
    obj1 = std::make_unique<namespace::class1>();
    if (obj1 != nullptr)
    {
        EXPECT_EQ(nullptr, devObjPtr);
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only interested in controlling the output of `class1::function()`, then you could use gMock like this:

```
class mock_class1 : public class1
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(int, function, ());
};

TEST(TestBase, Test_success)
{
    mock_class1 mock;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, function).WillOnce(Return(0));

    // Some code that invokes class1::function()...
}
```

If that doesn't answer the question, then you'll probably need to provide more information about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: In many places in the code the code snippet is getting covered. The code coverage is not getting covered for these lines of code. So we wanted get the code covered by setting the condition (devObjPtr == nullptr).